# How to make text wrap when using Flexbox with flex-wrap: wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**The issue:** In my current layout I have boxes that have a specific height based on a criterium. I want to display data in that box/div using columns, but when I do that, items that gets to a second column overflows the parent container's width. (see image below)

Note: Resize your screen size to have the result I showed on the screenshot below
[image: The issue]

**The result I'm looking for:** I would like elements to take up as much space needed within the parent's container, potentially only overflowing on the Y axis (vertically). In other words, I'd like text to wrap into multiple lines. (see image below)

[image: The result I'm looking for]

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/sr9fj07m/

```html
<div
      style="
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
      "
    >
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
        <div style="background-color: red">Other text here</div>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
        <div style="background-color: red">Another text here</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style="
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          flex-shrink: 1;

        "
      >
        <div style="background-color: aqua;">
          random text goes here random text goes here random text goes here
          random text goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How can that be achieved? Thanks!

Edited:
What I'm looking for is a solution where I have no hardcoded widths and children rearranges automatically from top to bottom, wrapping into multiple columns (flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap), but does not overflow parent width, and so break text into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding here is the flex items will grow to meet the contents of the children, so in this case the div that is wrapping the long text is growing to meet the text length.  One solution to this would be to set a specific width on the divs.  The below will achieve your desired result but you will need to play around with the div width on the 3rd div to get the correct result.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div
      style="
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: blue;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: flex-start;
        width: 600px;
      "
    >
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
        <div style="background-color: red">Other text here</div>
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
        <div style="background-color: red">Another text here</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style="
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          flex-shrink: 1;
          width: 400px;
        "
      >
        <div style="background-color: aqua;">
          random text goes here random text goes here random text goes here
          random text goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "so in this case the div that is wrapping the long text is growing to meet the text length"
I dont' think this is true: the third div has *exactly* 600px of width, and if you put a bit less text (or much more), it still will have 600px width. This width comes from the parent div width (even if it is overflowing from the parent).

Comment: Yes and I believe that is due to the fact that it has a hard coded width.  Since the parent flex element has a hard coded width it is being told not to grow to meet the width of the inner contents.  Then by defining a width on the inner div, you are telling that one not to grow to meet the width of its contents thus getting the content to wrap within the div.

Comment: Try removing the 600px width constraint on the parent: the parent takes all the horizontal space it can, but the third child still overflows from the parent and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Your solution works but you have to hardcode exactly the dimension of the children that are wrapped if you want them to exactly match the available space on the parent. I would prefer to find a solution where the children adapt their width to match the one of the parent. But I'm not sure we can do it.

Comment: Yes this is the best solution that I can come up with for this specific case.  I am not exactly sure what sort of design you are going for but it would be better to define two separate columns and specify which divs go into which columns.  Then you can set a specified width per column (say 50%) then you can manage the content within each column.  (not sure if that makes sense haha)

Comment: hi @NickLans Thanks for suggestion, but what I'm looking for is a solution where I have no harded-coded widths and children rearranges automatically from top to bottom, wrapping into multiple columns (flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap), but does not overflow parent width, and so break text into multiple lines. (like I showed on the screenshot "I'm looking for")
I'm looking for solution that would work on different screen widths out of the box.

And btw: I have added that static width for the parent container just to emulate a device with smaller screen.

Comment: and btw, text div in "aqua" color seems to overflow the exact same width as the largest element on its left. It is as if it does not account for other elements within the container... as if it is alone there.